# need a regular expression without space and minimum 5 characters, max 20

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression which accepts the alphabets UPPER CASE,lower case and digits
minimum character is 5 and maximum character is 20.
This is my current Reg Ex.

> ^[A-Za-z\d]{5,20}$

The issue that I am facing with the current Regular expression is,
if I enter 5 spaces it accepts. so I want the user to enter password without space.

Comment: Looks good to me, slight modification: ^[\w\d]{5,20}$

Comment: As Jay says, it looks fine. Another slight modification ^\w{5,20}$ because the \w includes 0-9 digits. \w matches any alphanumerical character (word characters) including underscore (short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: @jay: thanks jay.. let me try it out..
@simon: as per my requirement i am supposed to have apbhabets+digits as my password. I am using ASP.NET MVC, i tried to use the regular expression what u guys suggested, still the validation is not firing.

Comment: Can you update the question to show us how your code is using the regex? As others have stated the pattern is fine, so perhaps there's some other detail that may help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Looks fine. I would use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$`

Comment: if this is for a password why limit the length of the password, you are only going to store the hash anyway right?

Comment: @Jay Zeng: No, `\w` includes the underscore, which was explicitly not part of the specification.

Comment: @Tomalak - You are absolutely right and thanks for correcting me. I just looked it up: \w word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), so a better regex in this case will be:  ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a RegularExpressionValidator? If so you should add a RequiredFieldValidator to prevent whitespace or blank entries. Per the [RegularExpressionValidator documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

> Validation succeeds if the input
>   control is empty. If a value is
>   required for the associated input
>   control, use a RequiredFieldValidator
>   control in addition to the
>   RegularExpressionValidator control.

Comment: @Ahmed: I am not using Regular expression validator as i am working on ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$
```

Comment: Which might be more as intended, as most people don't seem to expect that \d matches all kinds of numeric Unicode characters (like Arabic numberals and such), as far as I know.

Comment: @peSHIr - Thanks for point it out, didn't know \d matches Unicode. By the chance you can give me an example?